# Inheritance of attributes sets

Tags: attributes, attribute-set, upgrade, inheritance

I created a simple hierarchy of attribute sets, basing each one on its parent attribute set, adding attributes in each level.

Now I discovered that one ancestor attribute set needed another attribute.

I went to the children of this ancestor after adding the attribute, and for my surprise the attribute isn't added to the children.

Is this intentional ? What am I missing ?

Thanks.

Comment: can you please update your code?

Comment: No code here, just using the backend.

Comment: then one option reindex

Comment: I don't use this attribute for layered navigation, so indexing won't add this new attribute to children sets

Comment: Then I don't know some one other guide you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attribute sets in Magento only use the Based On field for determining what attributes are a part of that set initially.

Unfortunately, once the attribute set creation has finished, there is no inheritance. You can see this fact if you look in the database in `eav_attribute_set`, and you will see there is no `parent` or `based_on` column.

**You will need to manually add that attribute to any attribute set that is necessary.**

Comment: Thanks for the precision. What about extensions that add this feature of inheritance ?

Comment: I have looked, but haven't seen anything like this. Maybe this would be a good one to write... Please remember to mark this as an answer if it answers your original question.

Comment: Yes. It seems simple to add, but not immediate how to make the system recognize the inheritance tree.

Comment: If you find this question interesting, up vote it too =)